# unable to append to array in swift

Tags: swift3

I have this class: Part of it

```
/// <#Description#>
public class CartManager: NSObject{
    static let sharedInstance: CartManager = { CartManager() }()

    // This is the product array
    public var productsArray = [ProductObject]()

    // These are the strings that will be passsed to the ShoppingCart
    var tempProData0:String!
    var tempProData1:String!
    var tempProData2:String!
    var tempProData3:String!
    var tempProData4:String!
    var tempProData5:String!
    var tempProData6:String!
    var tempProData7:String!
    var tempProData8:String!
    var tempProData9:UIImageView!
    var tempProData10:String!
    var tempProData11:String!

    /*
    // Create Singleton
    class var sharedInstance: CartManager{
        struct Static{
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: CartManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken){
            Static.instance = CartManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }*/

    // add the product to the array
    func addProduct(product: ProductObject){
        // Before we add the product we need to check if it is already added
        var tempIds = [Int]()
        for tempProdcut in productsArray{
            tempIds.append(tempProdcut.getProductId())
        }

        if (tempIds.contains(product.getProductId())){
            Toast(text: "Product staat al in de lijst", duration: Delay.long).show()
            print("Cart Manager, Product was aleady added")
        } else{
            print("Cart Manager, Product is added: \(product.getProductNaam()) .")
            self.productsArray.append(product)
            Toast(text: "Product is toegevoegd", duration: Delay.long).show()
        }
    }
}
```

From there I use this to append a product:

```
let cartman = CartManager()
cartman.addProduct(product: productToAdd)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The array length is always 0.
I tried many things but very got it working. 
The thing is the code was made in swift2 and it was working there but now in swift 3 I'm unable to get the product append to the array.

Thanks.

Comment: There are several issues with your code. First of all, why do you copy the contents of your array into a temporary array instead of just using the `filter` function on it and checking if it contains the new product? Secondly, why don't just use a Set, which guarantees that you will only have unique values. Moreover, the singleton instantiation that is commented out is way overcomplicated.

Comment: most of that could just be changed with `productsArray.contains(where: { $0.getProductId() == product.getProductId() })`

Comment: I agree but it is not the problem. I'm still optimizing the code. But I'm unable to append to the productArray(). There are no errors or warnings. So would Set be the solution. And why did this code work in Swift2 but now not anymore. Thanks for the help guys